# How to pass a parameter in defrule function? CLIPS

Tags: artificial-intelligence, rules, clips

I am new of CLIPS, thanks for your help.
THE ISSUE:
If I have below template:

```
(deftemplate user
  (slot id (type INTEGER))
  (slot firstname (type STRING))
  (slot lastname (type STRING))
  (slot username (type STRING))
  (slot average (type FLOAT))
  )
```

I would take the username value from facts and checking if there are two facts with same username but different average. For example, if We have:

```
(assert user (id 1) (firstname 'Mike') (lastname 'Mikeson') (username 'mike') (average 70.00))
(assert user (id 1) (firstname 'Mike') (lastname 'Mikeson') (username 'mike') (average 10.00))
(assert user (id 2) (firstname 'John') (lastname 'Johnson') (username 'john') (average 90.00))
```

I would count the facts with same username, so 'mike', and checking if first fact has same value in second fact in the average field.

I tried searching on internet but there are few information about CLIPS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
         CLIPS (6.4 2/9/21)
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate user
   (slot id (type INTEGER))
   (slot firstname (type STRING))
   (slot lastname (type STRING))
   (slot username (type STRING))
   (slot average (type FLOAT)))
CLIPS>   
(deffacts users
   (user (id 1) (firstname "Mike") (lastname "Mikeson") (username "mike") (average 70.00))
   (user (id 1) (firstname "Mike") (lastname "Mikeson") (username "mike") (average 10.00))
   (user (id 2) (firstname "John") (lastname "Johnson") (username "john") (average 90.00)))
CLIPS>    
 (defrule different-averages
    (user (username ?un) (average ?avg1))
    (user (username ?un) (average ?avg2&:(> ?avg2 ?avg1)))
    =>
    (println "User " ?un " has averages " ?avg1 " and " ?avg2 "."))
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
User mike has averages 10.0 and 70.0.
CLIPS>
```

Comment: Thanks for your useful help. Is it possible to save the print "User mike has averages 10.0 and 70.0" on a text file instead of print it on screen?

Comment: Look in section 12.4, I/O Functions, of the CLIPS Basic Programming Guide. You can use the functions open, printout, format, and close to do file I/O.